# JMeter - mobile devices requests emulation with JSR223 & groovy - No such property: ExpectedConditions error

Tags: jmeter, emulation, client-side, jsr223, mobile-devices

I'm trying to emulate https requests from mobile devices for client-side performance testing, using JSR223 + groovy, and the problem is that I couldn't perform in this way click on "Accept All Cookies" span element on page.

Response:

> Response message:javax.script.ScriptException:
> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
> such property: ExpectedConditions for class: Script7

In 'desctop' part of script, xpath (implemented via WebDriver sampler) and click on this "Accept All Cookies" span element works 100% correctly - and by this reason I know, that xpath is correct.

Could you please take a look at the problem and share your thought and any tips, where could be the reason of problem in JSR223 and how is possible to solve it?

Code is here:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "${webdriver_path}");

Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", ${width});
deviceMetrics.put("height", ${height});
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", ${pixelRatio});
Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "${userAgent}");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
//DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
//capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://${HOST_MAIN}");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Accept All Cookies')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Accept All Cookies')]")).click();

//this way doesn't work too:
//WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Accept All Cookies')]"))).click();

log.info(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

How can I implement the same action when emulating mobile devices on client-side using JSR223?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo or a copy-paste issue to me, you need to change this like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
```

to this line:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

as it has to be fully qualified and correct [ExpectedConditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class name

Also don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts because:

1. They are cached and on subsequent iterations you will get the same value
2. They may resolve into something causing logic malfunction or compilation failure
3. They conflict with Groovy [GString templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)

so instead of `"${webdriver_path}"` use `vars.get("webdriver_path")` and so on where `vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details